# MySQL variable `max_allowed_packet` auto resetting to 1MB

Tags: mysql

MySQL variable auto setting to 1MB every day. I have already set it to the 256MB in MySQL config. I have enabled General query Log to see who is changing the variable and found that someone has fired `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1024` to set this variable.

Is there any way to prevent user setting this variable from query?

How to revoke privileges from user for updating config variables?

Comment: You should modify the value from configuration file otherwise it will be reset. It is supposed to be somewhere in /etc folder (I assume you use Linux). Probably my.ini or my.conf

Comment: I have already modified the value to 256M in `my.cnf` . I just want to know Is there any to prevent user setting this variable from query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, you should revoke "super" privileges. It gives permission to use `SET GLOBAL`.

```
REVOKE SUPER ON *.* FROM 'username'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super