# Mysql ERRO: Packet for query is too large (2116 > 1024)

Tags: mysql

I am using Mysql 5.6 server only, and facing a weird problem related to  max_allowed_packet, I have changed mysqld section to 50M but after some executions the problem bring back.

```
#max_allowed_packet = 50M
```

I made some changes in config file but i cant repair.

Anyone have ever faced that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your configuration to allow more than educated guesses.

Comment: the # means that section is a comment just remove it

Comment: This workaround works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702336/mysql-variable-max-allowed-packet-auto-resetting-to-1mb